# How can I make my button look more like the Floating Action Button from Android JellyBean (v21)?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

How do I make my button look more like the Floating Action Button?

My button so far looks close but as yet, doesn't look the same. What other changes would you suggest?

An image of what the Floating Action Button looks like is below, as is an image of my button so far and my code so far

**An image of the actual Floating Action Button is below:**

[image]

**An image of my actual Button so far is below:**

[image]

**My API is v19**

**Code:**

**Code for actual button**

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:background="@drawable/addbutton"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="310dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffff" />
```

**Addbutton.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#08000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="3px"
                        android:left="3px"
                        android:right="3px"
                        android:top="3px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#09000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="2px"
                        android:left="2px"
                        android:right="2px"
                        android:top="2px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#10000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="2px"
                        android:left="2px"
                        android:right="2px"
                        android:top="2px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#11000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#12000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#13000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#14000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#15000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#16000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#17000000"/>
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="1px"
                        android:left="1px"
                        android:right="1px"
                        android:top="1px"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#FF4186"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: my minimum sdk is 19

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Result:

[image: resulting button]

---

Button in a layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ...

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom|end">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/add_button_selector"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="+"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:elevation="3dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,UnusedAttribute"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

### Explanation:

- RelativeLayout, overlays everything and places the button at the bottom-right corner.
- `margin` provides some space for the elevation
- `gravity` centers the background drawable and the text
- `stateListAnimator` set to null so it doesn't mess with elevation (it can be animated via this)

---

**res/drawables-v21/add_button_selector.xml**

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#b0372c">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#da4336" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

**res/drawables/add_button_selector.xml:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/add_button_selected"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/add_button_selected"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_button"/>
</selector>
```

**res/drawables/add_button.xml:**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#da4336" />
</shape>
```

**res/drawables/add_button_selected.xml:**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#b0372c" />
</shape>
```

### Explanation:

- Since API 21 you can use the ripple effect:
  [image: ripple effect]
- However for older versions you'll have to stick with the good old color selector

---

### Notes

- There may be a user-made ripple library for lower APIs, that might be worth checking out
- Lower APIs may need to use shadow and/or a custom drawable instead of elevation, haven't tested that since I don't have a proper device

Comment: Works well for me but only when I remove ripple wrapper, obviously I don't see any ripple effect when I press.

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich what device and API version?

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich L is a year old preview + you didn't specify the device. These 2 things render your comments useless.

Answer (score 1):

I build this kind of button in my app using this code

Code in Fragment.xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/contact_list_add_button"
    android:layout_width="65dip"
    android:layout_height="65dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button_shape"
    android:text="@string/action_plus"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="35sp" />
```

Code for drawable (round_button_shape)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#44aaaaaa"/>
            <padding 
                android:left="2dip"
                android:right="2dip"
                android:top="2dip"
                android:bottom="2dip"
                />            
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#90aaaaaa"/>
            <padding 
                android:left="2dip"
                android:right="2dip"
                android:top="2dip"
                android:bottom="2dip"
                />                        
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#ffaaaaaa"/>
            <padding 
                android:left="1dip"
                android:right="1dip"
                android:top="1dip"
                android:bottom="1dip"
                />                        
        </shape>
    </item>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_shape" android:left="1dip"         
    android:top="1dip" android:right="1dip" android:bottom="1dip"/>  
</layer-list>
```

Code for round shape Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="@color/red_dark"/>
</shape>
```

Additionaly i would recommend to use this code within a selector to provide feedback if the user interact with the button

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the following library for my app (I'm not the author).
It seems to work very well, looks just like a FAB and even can be easily attached to a listview to autohide when you scroll down. 
The library is easy to add through gradle too.
The image/animation on the github page makes the button look low quality but it isn't in real life and looks exactly like the google versions.

https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton