# Is there a name for this add / plus type of button in Android app development? If so, how can I add it to my application?

Tags: android, button, addition

In many popular apps I have seen the type of button below (this one is from Google Keep's mobile app). The "add" button is very intuitive and I'd like to add it to an app I am working on.

What is the name of this type of button?

[image: Does anyone know what the name of the button is and how to add it in Android app dev?]

I am just getting started out with developing in Android so please don't skewer me. Thanks, Scott.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make my button look more like the Floating Action Button from Android JellyBean (v21)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985466/how-can-i-make-my-button-look-more-like-the-floating-action-button-from-android)

Comment: "I am just getting started out with developing in Android so please don't skewer me" -- shouldn't you be more focused on [getting the Orlando Magic up to snuff](http://espn.go.com/nba/story/_/id/12976735/scott-skiles-hired-orlando-magic-coach)? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Floating Action Button (a.k.a, FAB). There is an edition of it in the Android Support Design Library and a variety of open source alternatives.